# Find moments of a discrete process using $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, expected-value, laplace-transform

For a linear process relating a variable $Y_i$ to random, independent variables $X_i$ using the equation:

\begin{equation}
Y_i = aY_{i-1} + (1-a)X_i
\end{equation}

which has the solution:

\begin{equation}
Y_n = a^nY_0 + (1-a)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i X_{n-i}
\end{equation}

it is relatively straightforward to investigate how the moments of the input ($X_i$) are transformed into the m$th$ moments of the output ($Y_i)$ using the expectation of the expansion of $(Y_i-\mu_{Y_i})^m$. Using this method (and assuming $Y_0=0$, $|a|<1$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$) it can be shown that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\left[Y_n\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[X_n\right] \quad \mathbf{var}\left[Y_n\right] = \frac{\left(1-a\right)^2}{1-a^2}\mathbf{var}\left[X_n\right] = \frac{1-a}{1+a}\mathbf{var}\left[X_n\right] \quad \mathbf{skew}\left[Y_n\right] = \frac{\left(1-a\right)^3}{1-a^3}\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^3}\mathbf{skew}\left[X_n\right]
\end{equation}

and so on. I have calculated these expressions for up to the 5th moment and have verified them numerically.

However, if I use a more complicated version of this simple system (for example, cascading through several such recursions) the expectations models become very cumbersome.  I am therefore looking to obtain these moment relationships between output, input and the linear process parameter $a$ using the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the impulse-response function for the system.  I have determined that this would be:

\begin{equation}
H\left(z\right) = \frac{z\left(1-a\right)}{z-a}
\end{equation}

which arises from:

\begin{equation}
Y(z) -az^{-1}Y(z) = (1-a)X(z) \quad \mbox{so} \quad Y(z) = \frac{z(1-a)}{z-a}X(z) \quad \mbox{and so} \quad H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}
\end{equation}

and that, for example the first moments from this would be:

\begin{align}
\mu_0^{'} &= H(z)_{z=1} = 1\\
\mu_1^{'} &= \left[-z\frac{d}{dz}H(z)\right]_{z=1} = \frac{a}{1-a}\\
\mu_2^{'} & = \left[-z\left(-z\frac{d}{dz}H(z)\right)\right]_{z=1} = \frac{a(1+a)}{(a-1)^2}
\end{align}

and that the second central moment should be given by:

\begin{equation}
\mu_2 = \mu_2^{'}-(\mu_1^{'})^2 = \frac{a}{(1-a)^2} 
\end{equation}

Clearly, this is not the same as above - where am I going wrong?  And how would I apply this to the higher moments up to the 5th or 6th?

Comment: There are at least two errors in your expressions: firstly, the solution to the system is $Y_n = a^nY_0 + (1-a) \sum_{i = 1}^n a^{n-i}X_i.$ Secondly the means are *not* equal unless the $X_i$s and $Y_0$ all have the same mean (otherwise the mean of $Y_i$s would depend on the means and $a$). Do you intend that all these means are identical?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 - thank you for pointing those out - I hope my edits have clarified?

Comment: Okay - I still think you need some condition on the $X$ means to make the claim that the $X$ and $Y$ means are equal. Indeed, you have $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = a\mathbb{E}[Y_0] + (1-a)\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} a^{n-i}\mathbb{E}[X_i] $, and its not at all obvious that the latter expression equals $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$.

Comment: Oh, finally I don't think I understand why evaluation at $1$ (which works out sums, usually) gives you the means. In my understanding to extract the means of the $Y$s as a sequence you would run the contour integration $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[ \oint z^{n-1} H(z) \mathcal{Z}_X(z)\mathrm{d}z].$ Taking small enough radii, you should be able to hit this with Fubini to get $\oint z^{n-1} H(z) \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{Z}_X(z)]\mathrm{d}z,$ which evaluates to the expected $ (1-a)\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} a^{n-i}\mathbb{E}[X_i].$

Comment: To further work out the second moments, you would need to work out the $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of $Y_n^2$ (which is an appropriate convolution), and then use the same process to extract coefficient. I don't know if this is all that useful if you need the concrete answers, but you might get a nice representation in terms of convolutions.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 When $X$ is $\mathbb N$-valued, the $z$-transform $H(z)$ is $\mathbb E[z^X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k P(X=k)$, so $H'(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{k-1} P(X=k)$, and $H'(1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k P(X=k) = \mathbb E[X]$.

Comment: @hydrologist I do not see how $\mathbb E[X_n] = \mathbb E[Y_n]$ can be true. For example, if $Y_0 = 0$, then we have $Y_1 = a\cdot 0 + (1-a) \cdot X_1$. Then $\mathbb E[Y_1] = (1-a) \mathbb E[X_1]$. This is only equal to $\mathbb E[X_1]$ if $a=0$, in which case your discrete process is not doing very much. **Separately** $H(z) = \frac{z(1-a)}{z-a}$ is not the $z$-transform of $Y_n$; it is the $z$-transform of a $\text{Geometric}(1-\frac1a)$ random variable. The $z$-transform of $Y_n$ should depend on the $z$-transforms of $X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yeah, so this is the (not too important) distinction between Z-transforms ($\sum a_i z^{-i}$ as I was taught them in an EE degree) and generating functions $\sum a_i z^i$. The OPs transfer function has a $z$ in the numerator which suggests they're using the $z^{-i}$ notation, in which case the inverse has a contour integral. Also, note that here is the Z-transform of the series $Y$ is computed, not the law of a single random variable, and so the mean of the derivative evaluated at $1$ (with generating functions) would be $\sum k E[Y_k]$, not the mean of some single $Y$.

Comment: Oh, and, of course, the derivative of just the transfer function doesn't even get you that.

Comment: @MishaLavrov - thanks for your comments.  Do my updates help?  I assume that I am looking for moments of $Y(z) = H(z)X(z)$ and therefore I need to differentiate with the chain rule and successively substitute to find the moments of $Y(z)$ in terms of the moments of $X(z)$ ?

Comment: The $z$-transform where $Y(z)$ is defined as a sum of $Y_i z^{-i}$ (which I am new to) is not the kind of $z$-transform that you can differentiate to find moments. The $z$-transform that you differentiate to find moments (which is the kind I'm familiar with) is a series defined in terms of just a single $Y_i$.